# javascript integer bug (number gets reduced by 1)

Tags: javascript

number 10205558742352809 gets reduced to 10205558742352808.
What?

Comment: exactly how are you using this number? and note that in JS, all numbers are fundamentally floats, and your number exceeds the 2**53 range that ints can be represented in exactly.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin). It should explain everything. The problem is that you exceeded the maximum integer value that can be used safely.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Floating-point numbers can be screwy.

**Long Answer**

Javascript uses [64-bit floating point numbers (IEEE-754)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number). The binary that makes up a floating point number is composed of 3 parts: sign bit (1 bit), exponent field (11 bits), and the significand field (52 bits). [There are plenty of sources online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) that go into further detail about how this works.

If we convert 10205558742352809 to it's binary format then interpret that as hexadecimal for readability we get:

```
434220F367C941D4
```

Which is the same thing you'd get for 102...09. Compare that with 102...10:

```
434220F367C941D5
```

So 102...09 is not directly representable in IEEE-754 and in fact lies on the border between 102...08 and 102...10.